# Swift String lastPathComponent

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, nsurl

I have an extension of String like this:

```
extension String {
    var fileURL: URL {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: self)
    }

    func appendingPathComponent(_ string: String) -> String {
        return fileURL.appendingPathComponent(string).path
    }

    var lastPathComponent:String {
        get {
            return fileURL.lastPathComponent
        }
    }

   var deletingPathExtension: String {
    return fileURL.deletingPathExtension().path
   }
}
```

Problem is `lastPathComponent` contains '/' as opposed to `NSString` counterpart which doesn't contains this. What is an elegant workaround? Didn't find an elegant answer in StackOverflow.

EDIT: Here is the real code that gives me issues:

```
  filenameField.text = path.lastPathComponent.deletingPathExtension
```

I fixed it by switching the two routines, i.e.

```
  filenameField.text = path.deletingPathExtension.lastPathComponent
```

Comment: `"/abc/def/xyz".lastPathComponent` returns `"xyz"` without a slash. Can you add a concrete example demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Get used to use URLs. There must be a reason why Apple removed the path manipulating API from `String`

Comment: I updated the code. It is actually deletingPathExtension that is appending /. Please suggest correct code.

Comment: What's the content of `path`? What result do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: @OOPer I posted an edit. it was actually deletingPathComponent that is the cause of issue.

Comment: Where's your _edit_ ? I asked you to include the actual content of `path`, the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: path was /var/Documents/.../IMG_001, path.lastPathComponent.deletingPathExtension output is /IMG_001

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest to use

```
(str as NSString).lastPathComponent
```

You won't create new objects in that case.